# passing jquery variable to php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html

can some help me that where i am going wrong. I need to display the jquery data in php 
html page(test.html)

```
<select id="combo" onclick="calcola()">
    <option>*</option>
    <option>/</option>
    <option>+</option>
    <option>-</option>
</select>
<script>
    function calcola() {
        var element = document.getElementById("combo");
        var op = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
        $ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: ({
                combo: op
            })
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

PHP Code(test.php):

```
<?php
$src1 = $_POST['combo'];
echo json_encode($src1);
?>
```

Comment: The php code(test.php) <?php 

$src1= $_POST['combo']; 
echo json_encode($src1); 
?>

Comment: Edit your question to include the php code, dont put it in a comment

Comment: You mean add response `data` from `success` into html . right? If it is where you want to be add?

Comment: There is no such thing as a jQuery variable: jQuery is not a programming language

Comment: Ranjith you are right, i want to display the axaj retrieved values in to php echo

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML Code should be:

```
<select id="combo" onchange="calcola()"> <!-- changed event -->
    <option value="*">*</option>
    <option value="/">/</option>
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
</select>
```

You are missing one comma `,` & one dot `.` in Javascript code. Code should be:

```
<script>
        function calcola() {
            var selectedValue = $("#combo").val();
            $.ajax({ //<-- One . was missing before ajax
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'test.php',
                data: { combo: selectedValue }, // <-- Comma was missing here
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

> You can bind events on element using jQuery.

Comment: @Sank, try new updated code. I found issues in HTML code too.